# Package not found: Com.Google.Android.Webiew

Tags: android, kotlin, crashlytics, android-developer-api, firebase-crash-reporting

I am I am getting this crash on splash but there I am not using any webview in splash screen. How can I fix it. I am getting this crash in firebase.

how to fix

```
Package not found: Com.Google.Android.Webiew RuntimeException
```